# Pre 2000 movie cyborg hunting humans for entertainment

Tags: story-identification, movie

Plot involves lower class people kidnapped and set loose in a run down industrial complex while a cyborg hunts them down. The place is rigged up with cameras and a group of wealthy teens is making bets on who's going to survive how long and how's going to be next to die. They have some control over the stalker and at least once, spare a victim, at least temporarily. She flashed the stalker and the viewer thought it was novel and entertaining enough to give her a stay of execution.

It was a private showing for the rich teens/young adults not a broadcast. At one point 2 of the rich spectators went into another room to have sex to pay off a bet. I remember it as a cyborg, half metal half man. I know at one point the cyborg disappeared to his special room to recharge and be cleaned after killing some of the kidnapped people.

Not *10th Victim*. American film. And not *Running Man*, one of my favorites. I do not remember any big name actors in it.

Comment: Could this be The 10th Victim - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tp8wRHNmniQ?

Comment: How do you know that the stalker is a cyborg, specifically, as opposed to an android or a human?

Comment: Could this possibly be the movie version of Stephen King's novel "The Running Man"? The stalkers in that 1987 film wore cyborg-ish costumes (I believe that one stalker had an electrocution weapon built into his gear).

Comment: @StanleyWebb: Also my thought, Wikipedia has a long plot outline; however it doesn't specifically mention the flashing scene. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Running_Man_(1987_film)

Comment: Not 10th victim. American film. And not Running Man, one of my favorites. I do not remember any big name actors in it.  It was a private showing for the rich teens/young adults not a broadcast. At one point 2 of the rich spectators went into another room to have sex to pay off a bet. I remember it as a cyborg, half metal half man. I know at one point the cyborg disappeared to his special room to recharge and be cleaned after killing some of the kidnapped people

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the film. [Mortal Challenge aka Death Game](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116060/) starring Timothy Bottoms and David McCallum (EVIL ducky). While I was digging through films I saw a poster for a film starring Nicholas Hill and recognized him from one of the scenes. Checked his IMDB and bingo!

> A devastating earthquake has left Los Angeles split in two. The wealthy now live in a new island metropolis, while the poor struggle to survive in the ruins of the old city. Detective Jack has been assigned to investigate the disappearance of a wealthy businessman's daughter somewhere in the ruined zone. While questioning some local punks, Jack and the others are suddenly attacked and kidnapped by a mysterious gang of thugs and taken to a hidden prison compound where they are hunted down by a strange half-man, half-machine killer. Somehow, Jack must find the girl and figure out who's behind this place, but first he must get out alive.—Jean-Marc Rocher (via IMDb)

Comment: Assuming you're the same Nick who asked this question to begin with, we'd be grateful if you'd merge your new account with the previous one by following the instructions provided [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts), and then mark your answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons on the left side of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.